# Tables or plots with weighted fonts

Tags: matlab, latex, tex

This might be a bit generic question. I am looking to create a table with fonts weighted (not necessarily linearly weighted) by magnitude. For example, I created this table in powerpoint, but the fonts are weighted manually.

[image]

The ultimate objective is that the table/plot goes to a journal article. I am open for solutions either based on `tex` table or as `matlab` plot. It would also be helpful to have community opinion, if this is good or bad idea (of weighting table/plot font by magnitude.)

P.S: The above figure is just an example. The color scheme does not matter and I am open for any color scheme.

Comment: This would be a low-readability figure to add to a journal article, you would probably be better to stick to the norm and use graded backgrounds (i.e. white through black for magnitude). This would be much clearer, as well as easier to implement.

Comment: @Wolfie: It was just an example from a presentation that I made. Color scheme does not matter. Added clarification on this.

Comment: Here is my opinion on this, and what the alternative could be: https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/730 — In short, you should make a graph, not a table.

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi You miss my point, do not resize the text, *instead* use different shading. Or, as Cris suggests, use a plot.

Comment: @Wolfie: Oh yes. I see what you mean.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Nice post. Very true

Comment: I was thinking of something like `\newcommand{\mynumber}[1]{\fontsize{#1}{#1}\selectfont #1}` but this wouldn't work for all integer values of `#1`. Maybe refining this line one may find a workaround